# Animation not working with FLAnimated image

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to animate my fishes so they go back and forth. My animation was working before I added my transition function to flip the fish so they go back and forth. I'm using a cocoa pod so I can display gifs in my fish animation. So I'm sure if my issue is with my code or if I used FLanimated image incorrectly. So far I've been treating it like a normal UIImageView.

```
        @IBAction func animateFish(_ sender: Any) {
        // Get the number of fish from the user

        let numberOfFish = Int(roundf(self.numFish!.value))
        for numFish in 1...numberOfFish{


        //Start a loop to show and animate fish one by one

        // Define the dimensions of the fish using randomization
        let wFish = (Int(arc4random() % 10)+1) * 20   // set fish width between 20 and 200
        let hFish = (wFish * 3) / 4                   // set fish height to be 75& of the width
        let xStart = 0 - wFish // fish starts outside left edge
        let xEnd = 380 + wFish                       //fish ends outside right edge
        let yPos = Int(arc4random() % 2) + wFish        // each fish starts at different vertical positions

        //Define the duration and delay of the animation
        let aDur = Double(arc4random() % 20)          // duration betweeen 0 and 9 secs
        let aDly = Double(arc4random() % 2)           // delay between 0 and 1 secs
        // Here's our fish gif
        let gifs = ["fishgif","fishFriendtoo"]
        //Now let's flip our image


        //for image 1
        let path1 : String = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "fishgif", ofType: "gif")!
        let imageData1 = try? FLAnimatedImage(animatedGIFData: Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path1)))
        //Now set our fish image
        let fish3 = FLAnimatedImageView()
        fish3.animatedImage = imageData1
        fish3.frame = CGRect(x: xStart, y: yPos, width: wFish, height: hFish)
        self.view.addSubview(fish3)
        let path2 : String = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "fishFriendtoo", ofType: "gif")!
        let imageData2 = try? FLAnimatedImage(animatedGIFData: Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path2)))

        let fish2 = FLAnimatedImageView()
        fish2.animatedImage = imageData2
        self.view.addSubview(fish2)
    var fishes = [imageData1, imageData2]
        //Now animate the fish and then make it go back and forth
    func goLeft(){
        UIView.animate(withDuration: aDur,delay: aDly, options: [.curveEaseInOut,.curveLinear,.repeat], animations: {fish3.frame = CGRect(x: xEnd, y: Int(arc4random()),width: wFish,height: hFish)}, completion: {
            animationFinished in

            flipper()
            goRight()})
    }
    func goRight()
    {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: aDur,delay: aDly, options: [.curveEaseInOut,.curveLinear,.repeat], animations: {fish3.frame = CGRect(x: 450, y: Int(arc4random()),width: wFish,height: hFish)}, completion: { animationFinished in
            flippertoo()
            goLeft()})
}
        func flipper(){
            fish3.animatedImage = imageData1}

        func flippertoo(){
            fish3.animatedImage = imageData2}
    }
}
```

Comment: You are calling flipper and go left at same time, you need to wait for completion of flipper to execute then call goRight in its completion Handler i.e you need 2 UIview.animation first Flip then its completion handler Second UIView.animate with move

Comment: @iOS Geek Let me rephrase so I understand. So I need to create two functions one with my flipping function and the other with a call to my function that changes directions. In the two functions I create I need to have separate animations, i.e. the 2 UIView animations. Is that correct?

Comment: Nested animation set , something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49934286/6080920 , check timerHandler UIview animations

Comment: Now I have an error that says 'Type of expression is ambiguous without more context' here's my functions that i rewrote func goLeft(){
            UIView.animate(withDuration: aDur,delay: aDly, options: [.curveEaseInOut,.curveLinear,.repeat], animations: {fish3.frame = CGRect(x: xEnd, y: Int(arc4random()),width: wFish,height: hFish)}, completion: {
                animationFinished in flipper()
            }) {(success) in goRight()}
        }

Comment: on which line ?